# inputs show in my fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a in a body page, but I want a fixed header when I scroll in page... I try more options but always show the inputs in the fixed header, I prove with Z-Index but I can't move the sliders after

This is a one example... 
[image]

I want a fixed bar with the canvas and their background and when scroll on page, this bar is fixed at top...

...

HTML :

```
<body style=" background-color:black;">
    <section id="headerHtml">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    </section>
<section id="bodyHtml" >
 .....
</selection>
</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var div = $('#headerHtml');
    var start = $(div).offset().top;

    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '10px' : '');

    });    
});
```

and CSS:

```
#headerHtml{
    background-image:url('fondo_nou.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:5px 20px;
}
```

thanks !!

Sorry for my english... I used the google translate :)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/ for us to see. I'm struggling to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: I can't reproduce in the jsfiddle because don't have bootstrap,  my idea is similar this : http://jsfiddle.net/yeco/4EcFf/ but the sliderBar overlaps my fixedMenu always

Comment: Thanks, I solve the problem! I used the navBar bootstrap and I solve It Thanks!!

Comment: That's good. Please post your solution as an answer as others may find it useful.

Comment: I post the solution,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used a Bootstrap NavBar for solve this problem, the code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <section id="headerHtml" style="background-color: black">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    </section>
</nav>
```